# SQL Server - Access denied when reading a file from Azure Blob Storage container using SAS key

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I have a requirement to read CSV files from an Azure blob storage. So far, this is throwing access denied errors every time I run my query:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL <myScopedCredential> 
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sv=2021-06-08&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rl&se=2023-03-31T09:38:05Z&st=2022-09-01T02:38:05Z...';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE <myExternalDatasource>
WITH ( 

    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE
    , LOCATION = 'https://<myResource>.blob.core.windows.net/<myContainer>'
    , CREDENTIAL= <myScopedCredential> --> 
);

SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK  '<folderName>/<fileName>.csv'
   , DATA_SOURCE = '<myExternalDatasource>'
   , FORMAT ='CSV'
   , FORMATFILE='<formatFilesFolderName>/<formatfileName>.fmt'
   , FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = '<myExternalDatasource>'
   , FIRSTROW = 2
) AS test
```

Below are some more details on how everything was setup:

- The storage account kind is of BlockBlobStorage.
- In the **Firewalls and virtual networks setting**, it is only **Enabled
  from selected virtual networks and IP addresses**. I already added my
  public IP address, as well as the IP address of Azure SQL Server
  which I got from here:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture?view=azuresql#gateway-ip-addresses
- The whole process works if I set it to Enabled from all networks. The
  SQL server and the storage account lives within the same resource
  group.
- I also configured a VNet that is both added for both of the resource.
- Saw this thread which is exactly similar to my issue, however the
  accepted answer is not working from my end: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58340185/cannot-bulk-load-because-the-file-file-csv-could-not-be-opened-operating-syst

I checked all the documentations regarding SAS access keys, database scoped credentials, external data sources and VNet networking and I don't see any limitations for SAS key access to be denied. Did I miss a configuration setup? I find it a little weird that in most cases, they are recommending to setup the storage account to be **Enabled from all networks**, which might be a security issue.

Comment: What is the trailing "..." in your SAS string?

Comment: Also, are you able to connect to the Storage Account using Azure Storage Explorer **and** are you able to run the same T-SQL batch from an on-prem SQL Server instance? (i.e. have you confirmed the issue _only_ affects your Azure SQL instance?)

Comment: @Dai I cutoff the whole SAS string just to show the starting part. I was able to use it to connect to Azure Storage Explorer and verified that the SAS key works.

Comment: To add more details, this command and approach works if the storage account is set to allow all public access, which I don't think we will be implementing.

Answer (score 0):

Please try enabling the Managed Service Identity on the Azure SQL Server and then ensuring the Blob Storage allows trusted Microsoft services to connect. Give the SQL Server Managed Service Identity the Storage Blob Data Contributor permissions and use the MSI as your credential. This [article](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/firewall-protected-azure-storage-and-azure-sql-database-load-data-using-t-sql-bulk-insert-command-9895b258e480) outlines the method and I believe it will also work for OPENROWSET.